# Div between two divs use as much as needed

Tags: html, css, web

I have 3 divs as followed

```
<div>
    <div id='left' style='background:red;float:left;height:150px;width:150px;'>
    </div>
    <div id='right' style='background:green;float:right;height:150px;'>
        <p>Hallo</p>
    </div>
    <div id='center' style='background:blue;height:150px;'>
        <p>Hallo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The center div should fill the space ONLY WHEN NEEDED. 
And just as much as possible and then it should show a horizontal scrollbar 
the last div should not be wrapped to the next line! 
Like I got it in the example above, it fills everything ALL THE TIME even when not needed.
But I need, that the right div is as near as possible to the center divs.

```
<div>
    <div id='left' style='background:red;float:left;height:150px;width:150px;'>
    </div>
    <div id='center' style='background:blue;float:left;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;'>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
    </div>
    <div id='right' style='background:green;height:150px;'>
        <p>Hallo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This Example shows what I want but in this case if I add some characters in the center div it wraps the right div to a new line like shown below:

```
    <div>
    <div id='left' style='background:red;float:left;height:150px;width:150px;'>
    </div>
    <div id='center' style='background:blue;float:left;white-space: nowrap;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden;'>
        <p>Hallo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
    </div>
    <div id='right' style='background:green;height:150px;'>
        <p>Hallo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be clearer on what you want, silly examples of what you don't want dont help. Draw a picture or explain in words.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem requires the use of JS to compute the width of the divs (because overflow will not work if width is not set) you are using then set the correct percentage width for it to be fluid.

Note that this answer will not work when you resize your browser (too lazy to do it)....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapperWidth = $('#wrapper').width(); // get width of main wrapper
    var wrapperRight = $('#right').width(); // get width of right
    var wrapperRight = (wrapperRight/wrapperWidth)*100; //get percentage width of right
    var wrapperLeft = (150/wrapperWidth)*100; //get percentage width of left
    var wrapperCenter = 100 - (wrapperLeft + wrapperRight); // get percentage width of center
    $('#left').css('width',wrapperLeft+'%'); // add inline css for width
    $('#center').css('width',wrapperCenter+'%'); // add inline css for width
    $('#right').css('width',wrapperRight+'%'); // add inline css for width
 });
</script>
<div id='wrapper' style='width: 100%;'>
    <div id='left' style='background:red;float:left;height:150px;width:150px;'>
    </div>
    <div id='center' style='background:blue;float:left; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;'>
        <p>Hallo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
        <p>Hallo</p>
    </div>
    <div id='right' style='background:green;height:150px; float: left;'>
        <p>Hallo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```